# Responses to meetings sent from O365 Group calendar are not received in the group inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar, microsoft-teams

I set up an O365 Group within Outlook for my team, with the hope of using the group calendar to organize our Teams meetings and other group activities.
So far, everything works as expected. However, one this that I noticed when testing was that responses to meetings from invited attendees that would normally appear as an e-mail to the organizer are not showing up in the group inbox. I can't seem to find them anywhere, and have not found any settings to enable that behavior. I do see the "Tracking" section of the event where I can see if invited individuals have accepted the meeting or now, but there is no way to see if any of the responses have typed-out responses, or if the meeting was forwarded to additional people, etc. Is there a way to turn on the expected e-mailed responses to the group inbox?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is the expected behavior and currently, the only way to see the responses in a group calendar is to check the **Tracking** tab.